# how to left and right swipe in tableview in iOS sdk

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to make a tableview in which i want jobs will change to swipe left and right .
By default in iphone swipe is for delete,so how can i make this.
i used gesture for that, but it does not look any transition in tableview,just swipe only,I want swipe transition will show like we are swapping.

Please help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method For Left Swipe**

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer * swipeleft=[[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeleft:)];
swipeleft.direction=UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
[yourtableviewName addGestureRecognizer:swipeleft];
```

**Method For Right Swipe**

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                     initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swiperight:)];
[gesture setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];
[tblvie addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
```

**left Swipe Action Method**

```
-(void)swipeleft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
     int tag = (int)recognizer.view.tag; // assign the tag if u need 
   if (tag==40)

  {
       // call the another function

    }
   else  
    {
       // call the some another function
     }
    [yourtableview reloadData];

  }
```

**Right Swipe Action Method**

```
-(void)swiperight:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
     int tag = (int)recognizer.view.tag; // assign the tag if u need 
   if (tag==40)

  {
       // call the another function

    }
   else  
    {
       // call the some another function
     }
    [yourtableview reloadData];

  }
```

Comment: if u need any assistance i surely hope with u

Comment: THanku anbu but i used this code but i jus t want the transition because tableview is not look swap..but it swap programatically..what should we used to look the transition left to right of right to left

Comment: oh then u need just like the answer what  Sefi posted

Comment: @JEET -- u need left and right swipe acton in each cell, if u swipe right show the **mark as read**,**twitter** etc and swipe left want to show **delete**,**more**